# Rolling up monthly data to quarterly

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have monthly data for each company and it's associated MRR (Monthly Revenue) as of the month end date. I am trying to build a quarterly report which shows the progression of the company within the quarter. Following is the reproducible sample dataset with quarter end dates:

```
WITH

quarter_end_date AS
(
SELECT '2021-04-30' q_end_date
UNION ALL
SELECT '2021-07-31' q_end_date
UNION ALL
SELECT '2021-10-31' q_end_date
UNION ALL
SELECT '2022-01-31' q_end_date
),

data AS
(
SELECT '2020-05-31' as_of_date, 'A' company_id, '100' mrr,'new' category
UNION ALL
SELECT '2020-06-30' as_of_date, 'A' company_id, '100' mrr,'no change' category
UNION ALL
SELECT '2020-07-31' as_of_date, 'A' company_id, '100' mrr,'no change' category
UNION ALL
SELECT '2020-08-31' as_of_date, 'A' company_id, '100' mrr,'no change' category
UNION ALL
SELECT '2020-09-30' as_of_date, 'A' company_id, '0' mrr,'churn' category
UNION ALL
SELECT '2020-10-31' as_of_date, 'A' company_id, '100' mrr,'new' category
UNION ALL
SELECT '2020-11-30' as_of_date, 'A' company_id, '100' mrr,'no change' category
UNION ALL
SELECT '2020-12-31' as_of_date, 'A' company_id, '0' mrr,'churn' category
UNION ALL
SELECT '2021-01-31' as_of_date, 'A' company_id, '0' mrr,'new' category
UNION ALL
SELECT '2021-02-28' as_of_date, 'A' company_id, '100' mrr,'no change' category
UNION ALL
SELECT '2021-03-31' as_of_date, 'A' company_id, '100' mrr,'no change' category
UNION ALL
SELECT '2021-04-30' as_of_date, 'A' company_id, '120' mrr,'expansion' category
UNION ALL
SELECT '2021-05-31' as_of_date, 'A' company_id, '90' mrr,'contraction' category
UNION ALL
SELECT '2021-06-30' as_of_date, 'A' company_id, '70' mrr,'contraction' category
UNION ALL
SELECT '2021-07-31' as_of_date, 'A' company_id, '100' mrr,'expansion' category
UNION ALL
SELECT '2021-08-31' as_of_date, 'A' company_id, '100' mrr,'no change' category
UNION ALL
SELECT '2021-09-30' as_of_date, 'A' company_id, '120' mrr,'expansion' category
UNION ALL
SELECT '2021-10-31' as_of_date, 'A' company_id, '90' mrr,'contraction' category
UNION ALL
SELECT '2021-11-30' as_of_date, 'A' company_id, '0' mrr, 'churn' category
),
```

The MRR dataset (above CTE data) doesn’t store company info once it churns (stops paying subscription or cancels the service). The approach I'm using is capable of capturing any churn which happens in the start of the quarter or the end of quarter but it doesn’t if churn happens within the quarter. My SQL:

```
step_1
AS(
SELECT *,
LAG(mrr,1) OVER (PARTITION BY company_id ORDER BY as_of_date) prev_m1_mrr,
LAG(mrr,2) OVER (PARTITION BY company_id ORDER BY as_of_date) prev_m2_mrr,
LAG(mrr,3) OVER (PARTITION BY company_id ORDER BY as_of_date) quarter_start_mrr,
FROM data
)

SELECT *
FROM step_1
CROSS JOIN quarter_end_date q
WHERE q.q_end_date = step_1.as_of_date
ORDER BY q.q_end_date DESC
```

Output:

| q_end_date | Company_id | mrr | category | prev_m1_mrr | prev_m2_mrr | quarter_start_mrr |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-10-31 | A | 90 | contraction | 120 | 100 | 100 |
| 2021-07-31 | A | 100 | expansion | 70 | 90 | 120 |
| 2021-04-30 | A | 120 | expansion | 100 | 100 | null |

Expected Output:

| q_end_date | Company_id | mrr | category | prev_m1_mrr | prev_m2_mrr | quarter_start_mrr |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-31 | A | null | churn | 0 | 0 | 90 |
| 2021-10-31 | A | 90 | contraction | 120 | 100 | 100 |
| 2021-07-31 | A | 100 | expansion | 70 | 90 | 120 |
| 2021-04-30 | A | 120 | expansion | 100 | 100 | null |

Comment: Is it possible to extend your data by populating entries for months December,2021 and January,2022? The populated entries should have proper month end dates but can be default values for other columns.
I'm suggesting this because the `JOIN` condition is not satisfied for the month January,2022 as it is not present in the `data` table.

Comment: Do you have the data of different companies in different tables?

Comment: quarter_start_mrr should be 120 or 90 for first row in expected output?

Comment: @KabilanMohanraj I can't add values to the table as it's not under my control.

Comment: @KrishanuSengupta All the companies are in a single table. 
My bad the quarter start MRR for the first row should be 120.

Comment: Consider accepting/upvoting the answer if you find it helpful, otherwise please let me know if I can improve anything.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that data of all companies are in the same table, otherwise the query will be straightforward. I added a few values with a second company ‘B’. The query works, but it will give ‘Churn’ as the category whenever data is not present in the entire quarter for that company.That also includes the period when the company did not even start using the service. That can be filtered out later with simple queries based on start date if needed.

Second thing is I added another CTE for the list of companies.

```
WITH
quarter_end_date AS
(
SELECT '2021-04-30' q_end_date
UNION ALL
SELECT '2021-07-31' q_end_date
UNION ALL
SELECT '2021-10-31' q_end_date
UNION ALL
SELECT '2022-01-31' q_end_date
),
companies as
(SELECT 'A'as company_id
union all
SELECT 'B'as company_id
),
data AS
(
SELECT '2021-02-28' as_of_date, 'A' company_id, '100' mrr,'new' category
UNION ALL
SELECT '2021-03-31' as_of_date, 'A' company_id, '100' mrr,'no change' category
UNION ALL
SELECT '2021-04-30' as_of_date, 'A' company_id, '120' mrr,'expansion' category
UNION ALL
SELECT '2021-05-31' as_of_date, 'A' company_id, '90' mrr,'contraction' category
UNION ALL
SELECT '2021-06-30' as_of_date, 'A' company_id, '70' mrr,'contraction' category
UNION ALL
SELECT '2021-07-31' as_of_date, 'A' company_id, '100' mrr,'expansion' category
UNION ALL
SELECT '2021-08-31' as_of_date, 'A' company_id, '100' mrr,'no change' category
UNION ALL
SELECT '2021-09-30' as_of_date, 'A' company_id, '120' mrr,'expansion' category
UNION ALL
SELECT '2021-10-31' as_of_date, 'A' company_id, '90' mrr,'contraction' category
UNION ALL
SELECT '2021-11-30' as_of_date, 'A' company_id, '0' mrr, 'churn' category
union all
SELECT '2021-10-31' as_of_date, 'B' company_id, '100' mrr,'no change' category
UNION ALL
SELECT '2021-11-30' as_of_date, 'B' company_id, '120' mrr,'expansion' category
UNION ALL
SELECT '2021-12-31' as_of_date, 'B' company_id, '90' mrr,'contraction' category
UNION ALL
SELECT '2022-01-31' as_of_date, 'B' company_id, '100' mrr, 'expansion' category
),
step_1
AS(
SELECT *,
LAG(mrr,1) OVER (PARTITION BY company_id ORDER BY as_of_date) prev_m1_mrr,
LAG(mrr,2) OVER (PARTITION BY company_id ORDER BY as_of_date) prev_m2_mrr,
LAG(mrr,3) OVER (PARTITION BY company_id ORDER BY as_of_date) quarter_start_mrr,
FROM data
)
SELECT q_end_date,c.company_id,
mrr,IFNULL(category,'churn') as category,IFNULL(prev_m1_mrr,'0') as prev_m1_mrr, IFNULL(prev_m2_mrr,'0') as prev_m2_mrr,IFNULL(quarter_start_mrr,lead(mrr) over (partition by c.company_id order by q_end_date desc)) as quarter_start_mrr
FROM  companies c cross join quarter_end_date q left join step_1 s  on q.q_end_date = s.as_of_date and c.company_id=s.company_id
ORDER BY company_id,q.q_end_date DESC
```

**Output:**
[image]